# Writing self modifying code in C on windows, Unable to write patch

Tags: c, windows, winapi, self-modifying

I'm trying to write some self-modifying code, but once i have found the location of were i want to write the patch to in memory, I am unable to actually write the patch to memory.

I have tried to use different ways of ensuring that the permissions on the area of memory im trying to patch are correct (`PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`) for what i want to do. I think the issue is in how i call `WriteProcessMemory` though im not sure why this is.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PATTERN "\x55\x48\x89\xe5\x48\x83\xec\x20\x48\x8d\x0d\x91\x2a\x00\x00\xe8\x3c\x16\x00\x00\x90\x48\x83\xc4\x20\x5d\xc3"
#define REPLACE "\x55\x48\x89\xe5\x90\x5d\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90x\90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\xc3"
#define LEN 27

DWORD SearchPattern(unsigned char* mem, unsigned char* signature, DWORD signatureLen) 
{
    ULONG offset = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 0x200000; i++) {
        if (*(unsigned char*)(mem + i) == signature[0] && *(unsigned char*)(mem + i + 1) == signature[1]) {
            if (memcmp(mem + i, signature, signatureLen) == 0) {
                // Found the signature
                offset = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return offset;
}

void patch_mem()
{
    DWORD oldProtect, oldOldProtect;

    unsigned char *exe = (unsigned char *)GetModuleHandle("patching_tests.exe");
    DWORD patternOffset = SearchPattern(exe, PATTERN, LEN);
    if (patternOffset == 0)
    {
        printf("Error finding offset, returning\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("offset: %#010x\n", (exe + patternOffset));

    VirtualProtect((exe + patternOffset), LEN, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
    CopyMemory((exe + patternOffset), REPLACE, LEN);
    VirtualProtect((exe + patternOffset), LEN, oldProtect, &oldOldProtect);

    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());
    if (!FlushInstructionCache(handle, (LPCVOID)(exe + patternOffset), LEN))
    {
        printf("FlushInstructionCache, %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    return;
}

int say_hi()
{
    printf("hi!\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("calling say_hi...\n");
    say_hi();

    printf("patching memory...\n");
    patch_mem();

    printf("calling say_hi again...\n");
    say_hi();

    return 0;
}
```

The aim is to modify the assembly in the `say_hi` function so it will just return rather than printing hi!

Could i also note that i would like to do this without using a pointer to the `say_hi` function and rather search for it in memory. This is because I'm going to be implementing this technique in a project where it will not possible to access a direct pointer to the function.

UPDATE:
I've removed the call to `WriteProcessMemory` and replaced it with `CopyMemory`. I've also now used `GetModuleHandle` to get the base address of the module. This will now compile on its own... though it still doesn't seem to overwrite the code in the `say_hi` function.

Comment: In what way does the code fail?

Comment: You don't need to use `(Read|Write)ProcessMemory()` when reading/writing memory in your own process. You can just read/write the memory directly, such as with `memcpy()` or `CopyMemory()`. Use `(Read|Write)ProcessMemory()` only when reading/writing memory in *other* processes than your own.

Comment: The code fails because it does not write to the location and the `say_hi` function still executes and is not just returning.

Comment: hmmm ive tried using `CopyMemory()` or `memcpy()` but im still unable to to get it to work using these methods. e.g `CopyMemory((LPVOID)(base_address + patternOffset), REPLACE, LEN)`

Comment: @Dylanhalls well, for starters, your code shouldn't even compile as shown, because `patch_mem()` tries to use `base_address` before it has even been declared. So this can't be your real code.

Comment: nah base address is declared at the top of the function at `unsigned char* base_address = GetProcessBaseAddress(GetCurrentProcessId());` i just havent included the whole `GetProcessBaseAddress` function

Comment: Then, please, provide a [example].

Comment: @RemyLebeau @thebusybee I've updated the code so it will now compile and run, sorry about that. I've also opted to use the `CopyMemory()` Remy suggested though I'm unsure that I'm using it correctly as it doesn't not appear to write to the new memory address.

Comment: @Dylanhalls Your 2nd call to `VirtualProtect()` is not using the same memory address as the 1st call. And after modifying executable code, you need to call [`FlushInstructionCache()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-flushinstructioncache). Also, you are not verifying that `SearchPattern()` is not returning 0, or returning the correct offset you are expecting. So it is possible you may not even be modifying `say_hi()` at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, I've fixed that call to `VirtualProtect()` and have added the call to `FlushInstructionCache()` while also checking that `SearchPattern()` is not returning 0. Though I'm not to sure that my arguments (specifically the `lpBaseAddress`) in my call to `FlushInstructionCache()` is correct as this still doesn't seem to overwrite the code... Thanks for the help so far tho. (I've update the code in the example to show my current code)

Answer (score 1):

First, in Macro `REPLACE`, there is an error `"\x90x\90"`, not sure if it is your writing error when posting.

Then, `int say_hi()` must have a return value, like

```
int say_hi()
{
    printf("hi!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

or just using `void` return type.

The function memory you are trying to modify may not be correct, or they may be skipped. Note that the pattern you are searching for will have the same data in different memory(because the `#define PATTERN` constant is defined in your program), so what you have modified is most likely the `PATTERN`.

You can check it by `memcmp(PATTERN, REPLACE, LEN);`:

```
DWORD SearchPattern(unsigned char* mem, unsigned char* signature, DWORD signatureLen)
{
    ULONG offset = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 0x20000; i++) {
        if (*(unsigned char*)(mem + i) == signature[0] && *(unsigned char*)(mem + i + 1) == signature[1]) {
            if (memcmp(mem + i, signature, signatureLen) == 0) {

                if (mem + i == signature)
                    continue;  //Found the memory of the PATTERN
                // Found the signature
                offset = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return offset;
}
```

I can find the execution instruction of `say_hi` through the **correct `PATTERN`** and modify it.